# C# .NET 7, I got Nullable Object must have a value when trying to query data from DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, nullable, .net-7.0

By using .NET 7, my code as below

```
    var query = from c in dbContext.Customers
                from o in dbContext.Orders.Select(o => new { Id = o.Id, Number = o.Number }).Where(o => o.CustomerId == c.Id)
               .DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                     Customer = c,
                     Order = o 
                };
    
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Reason I used anonymous type in Orders.Select statement is I only want to get 2 fields order id and order number to speed up the performance,

Some customers will not have any order, so in runtime, it will throw exception Nullable object must have a value with stack trace :

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Nullable object must have a value.
> Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_NoValue()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

Can you please advise what should I change to get rid of this exception, thank you for helping.

Tried to check null like below ways, but **does not work**

1. `dbContext.Orders.Select(o => o != null ? new { Id = o.Id, Number = o.Number } : new  { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Number = 0})`
2. `dbContext.Orders.Select(o => o != null ? new Order { Id = o.Id, Number = o.Number } : (Order) null)`
3. `select new { Customer  = c, Order = o != null ? o : new Order() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Number = 0}}`

Comment: Have you tried reversing the join. To me it looks like the join might fail when the Customer has no orders

Comment: I think either Customers or Orders is null.  It may be the properties so Try : Where(o => (o.CustomerId !=null) && (c.id != null) && (o.CustomerId == c.Id))

Comment: Customer cannot be null because they the main table from the query, for that reason i  can't reverse the join because Customers list is my purpose to showing all customers no matter what they got orders or not. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in dbContext.Customers
           join a in dbContext.Orders on c.CustomerId equals a.CustomerId into ps
            from suborder in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Customer = c,
                Order = suborder //deal with null, assign some generic object or whatever you need
            };

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I think that is what you are looking for. Just pls change your property names

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the query to perform the projection in the final projection:

```sql
var query = from c in dbContext.Customers
    from o in dbContext.Orders
        .Where(o => o.CustomerId == c.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Customer = c,
        Order = o == null
            ? null
            : new
            {
                o.Id,
                o.Number
            } 
    };
```

But you can also try explicitly specify the type for anonymous member:

```cs
var query = from c in dbContext.Customers
    from o in dbContext.Orders
        .Select(o => new { Id = (int?)o.Id, Number = o.Number })
        .Where(o => o.CustomerId == c.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Customer = c,
        Order = o 
    };
```

Note that you always can just setup the relationships correctly and do something like the following instead of writing join manually:

```cs
var list = ctx.Customers
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Customer = c,
        Orders = c.Orders.Select(o => new { o.Id, ... }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```